# Plus sign in htacesss rewrite for users

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite

I want to be able to create the url: http://example.com/+/user

Is it possible using .htacess rewrite.

I have searched the web and have come across nothing relevant to what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use really simple RewriteRule...

```
RewriteRule ^\+/user$ /test.php [PT,L,QSA,NC]
```

Or if you want to "catch" username from address, you have to use something like this

```
RewriteRule ^\+/(.+)$ /test.php?username=$1 [PT,L,QSA,NC]
```

With whatever rewrite_mod options you need.

Answer (score 0):

Not so much things to do, simple things are often better ones :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^\+/(.+)$  index.php?user=$1 [L]
```